# Error al ver un Post de Instagram en página web con HTML

Tags: html, css, html5, instagram

Tengo un post de Instagram que quiero incorporar a mi página web con HTML. El código (HTML) no lo puedo compartir ya que es demasiado extenso, pero empieza con la etiqueta `<blockquote>`. El problema no es que no se pueda incorporar, el problema es que no se puede ver. En la página, se visualiza de esta manera:
[image: Imagen sobre como se ve]

En realidad lo que quiero es que se vea la publicación y que no aparezca eso. No sé de que otra manera se puede hacerlo.

O en alternativa, hay alguna forma de crear un RSS que cuando se haga una nueva publicación, se vaya actualizando la publicación que aparece.

Lo que tengo de código es mínimo:

```
<div class="novedades container">
<blockquote>class="instagram-media" data-instgrm-captioned data-instgrm-permalink="https://www.instagram.com/p/CTIUKKDrFZr/?utm_source=ig_embed&amp;utm_campaign=loading" data-instgrm-version="13" <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/CTIUKKDrFZr/?utm_source=ig_embed&amp;utm_campaign=loading" style="...">Una publicación compartida por Venta de autos (@autos_enventa_arg)</a></p></div></blockquote> <script async src="//www.instagram.com/embed.js"></script>
</div>
```

Saludos!
Buenas Tardes!

Comment: Te recomiendo que añadas la porción de código que viene al caso. No es necesario todo el código de la página, sino solamente la porción en concreto. De lo contrario, no estás aportando información útil para resolver el problema.

Comment: Listo! Fijate si sirve.

Answer (score 0):

Así, de entrada, el código que has compartido está mal, pero entiendo que se debe a las ediciones que le has hecho porque es demasiado largo para compartirlo entero. Lo he probado en un JSFiddle normal y funciona perfectamente: https://jsfiddle.net/Bettylex/kqop7r5e/

Si en tu web queda atrapado en esa previsualización que dice "Ver publicación en Instagram" y no llega a cargar del todo es porque hay algo bloqueando el javascript de Instagram. O bien porque no has copiado bien el código, que también podría ser.

Comment: Perfecto! Muchas Gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

En que estas haciendo el proyecto?
Capaz tengas que consumir la API de visualización básica de Instagram para poder mostrar el contenido.

Si estas haciendo una web estática probablemente solo te deja consumir ciertos recursos de instagram nada mas.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).